# typescript multiple generics of the same type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a lot of lists that need to be casted to maps so i decided to create a `listToMap` function:

```
export function listToMap<T>(
  list: T[],
  keyAccesFn: (listElement: T) => string): Map<string, T> {
  const reducer = (accumulator: Map<string, T>, currentValue: T) => accumulator.set(keyAccesFn(currentValue), currentValue);
  return list.reduce(reducer, new Map<string, T>());
};
```

the function takes a list and a function which returns a string for a list element. The result is a Map with the returned string of `keyAccesFn` as key for the listelement the function was used on.

Now it occured that i not only have to extract the Maps key of the listed Objects but the value itself. I decided to apporach this by passing another function into the listToMap function which **might** return a new Type. The function looks like this atm:

```
export function listToMap2<T1, T2>(
  list: T1[],
  keyAccesFn: (element: T1) => string,
  valueAccesFn: (element: T1) => T2 = (element: T1) => element): Map<string, T2> {
  const reducer = (accumulator: Map<string, T2>, currentValue: T1) => accumulator.set(keyAccesFn(currentValue), valueAccesFn(currentValue));
  return list.reduce(reducer, new Map<string, T2>());
};
```

The **issue** is: i want to provide a default `valueAccessFn` that just returns the list elemnt so i could replace listToMap with `listToMap2`, but can't as typescript does not accept that generic type `T1` might be generic type `T2`. That annoys me espacially, as i have no other place where pass anything of `T2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with the default you specify:

1. Typescript will not use the default value for inference when you call the function, so even if you could set the default, it will not infer `T1=T2`
2. Since `T1` and `T2` are different types, just based on the method definition it can't tell that `T1` will be compatible with `T2`

Both problems can be solved, the first by specifying a default value for `T1`, and the second by using a type assertion to any for the default value.

```
export function listToMap2<T1, T2 = T1>(
    list: T1[],
    keyAccesFn: (element: T1) => string,
    valueAccesFn: ((element: T1) => T2) = ((element: T1) => element) as any): Map<string, T2> {
    const reducer = (accumulator: Map<string, T2>, currentValue: T1) => accumulator.set(keyAccesFn(currentValue), valueAccesFn(currentValue));
    return list.reduce(reducer, new Map<string, T2>());
};

listToMap2([''], k=> k) // Map<string, string>
listToMap2([''], k=> k, k=> k.length); //Map<string, number>
```

Comment: The default for types is some pretty nice thing, this answer allready solved me even more issues